# Laravel best way to store a function then retrieve it and execute it

Tags: laravel, serialization, queue

I am creating a payment page which uses PayFast.co.za.

When the user completes payment on the PayFast server, Payfast, in the background fires off a call to a script on the server(itn.php) to verify. then the user is redirected to the thankyou page. I use the thank you page to execute the function that iterates through the session data stored in their cart to update the database.

I want to do the executing of the cart data in the itn.php file instead of the thank you page.

So my question is... How do I store the data of a function(the thank you page) before the user is directed to Payfast servers and then retrieve it and execute it?

Do I use serialization? queues??

I notice when I am using queues for sending emails the data in the database is stored then executed later. I need to be able to store the cart data and associate it with the invoice id then recall that on the itn.php that Payfast is executing. Payfast is also sending the new invoice id to the itn.php page.

Comment: The `custom_str` and `custom_int` post fields of the PayFast integration can be used to send through cart data to PayFast which will then be returned to your `notify_url` via the ITN callback for you to make use of.

Comment: Hey Daniel. Thanks for the reply. I did consider the custom_str but I couldn't fit the entire cart contents in 255 characters. I eventually went for encoding the cart contents with json, storing with invoice table and associating it with the m_payment_id which was sent to the itn.php then decoded the json. job done!

Comment: Cool, you can answer your own question if you found a solution for it. Helps others in the future who might want to obtain the cart contents for the PayFast ITN.